# Show that $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z}$ has a holomorphic logarithm in $D(0,0,2 \pi)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z}$ has a holomorphic logarithm in $D(0,0,2 \pi)$

Comment: What is $D(0,0,2\pi)$? The disc centered at $z=0$ for $0\leq\theta<2\pi$?

Comment: $D(0,0,2 \pi)$ = { z$\in$ C | 0 < |z| < 2 $\pi$}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.  The singularity at $0$ couldn't be a pole, an essential singularity or a removable singularity.

EDIT: The answer is still no for the revised question. Let $w = 1/z$.  Your function is $f(w) = w \exp(w)$.
If $g(w)$ is a logarithm of $f(w)$ (in $\{w: |w| > 1/(2 \pi)\}$), then $g'(w) = f'(w)/f(w) = 1 + 1/w$.  An analytic function in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ can't have a $1/w$ term in the Laurent series of its derivative.

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question because it was wrong